# What does "wrought upon" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs, archaic-language

This context comes from the video game "Divinity Original Sin II"
the phrase I've difficulties with comes when I speak to a statue of a God trapped in some hellish realm because he was sent there by a character called Bracus Rex.

**Statue-** *
"Bracus Rex! Gods damn  you to this hell in which I suffer. Gods damn these burning flames!"*

**one of the dialogue options-***"Bracus Rex? Ask what evil the mad king's **wrought upon him**?"*

When I google the phrase "wrought upon somebody" the only result is from thefreedictionary which redirects me to a couple of phrases and on of them is:

**"work"**

1. To cause or effect; bring about: working miracles.

I know that wrought is the archaic version of work. Does the sentence simply mean "Ask what evil the mad king's **caused him**?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's probably a bit more than just "caused him": "caused him" wouldn't have to be intentional, but "wrought upon him" is.

Something like "inflicted upon him" would be closer. Work does not mean "inflict" **but wrought is now more often used as the past of wreak**, which does.

**[wreak](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wreaked)**

2. To inflict (vengeance or punishment) upon a person. (source: *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.*)

Comment: Can you provide a definition for "work: that means inflict? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: _Work_ does not mean "inflict". But _wrought_ is now more often used as the past of [_wreak_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wreak), which does.